# How do you write object literal line coverage in Typescript Mocha unit-test?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

**Lead:**
New to working with typescript and writing unit tests using *Mocha* and *Chai*.

**Question**
Any tips on how I can go about getting 100% line coverage in unit tests with an object literal that isn’t in a class?  Trying to avoid going static if at all possible, but unit testing still has to hit 100% to pass.

```js
// constants.ts
export default {
    path: “./example”,
    name: “Example Name”
}
```

```js
// constants.spec.ts
// How do I unit test ‘export default’ for 100% line coverage?
// I have tried

import chai from "chai";
import * as constants from “./constants.ts”;

describe(“constants”, () => {
    it(“Constants literals should have a length of 2“, () => {
        chai.expect(constants.default.length).equal(2); 
    });
});

// The mocha test succeeds, but the line still says it hasn’t been tested.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, but I am sure there is an easier way to use and test literals in Typescript.

```js
describe("Constants", async () => {
    it("can be created", async () => {
        const obj = constants.default;
        chai.should().exist(obj);
    });
});
```

[Typescript Mocha Chai unit-test 100% line coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MS6v.png)